# Custom info window for selected place not showing up (Google Maps/Places API)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using the Google Places API, and have implemented their `pickPlace` function which looks like this:

```
func pickPlace() {
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.708637, longitude: -74.014839)
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + 0.001, longitude: center.longitude + 0.001)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - 0.001, longitude: center.longitude - 0.001)
    let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

    placePicker.pickPlace(callback: {(place, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let place = place {
            // Set place to class variable selectedPlace
            self.selectedPlace = place
            // Add marker & move camera to new place
            if self.selectedPlace != nil {
                let cam = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: (self.selectedPlace?.coordinate)!, zoom: 18)
                let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: cam)
                let newPlaceMarker = GMSMarker(position: (self.selectedPlace?.coordinate)!)
                newPlaceMarker.map = mapView
                self.navigationItem.title = self.selectedPlace?.name
                print(self.selectedPlace?.website)
                newPlaceMarker.title = self.selectedPlace?.name
                self.view = mapView
            }

        } else {
            self.navigationItem.title = "No place selected"
        }
    })
}
```

So this allows the user to search for a place like "Starbucks" and sets `place` to the variable `var selectedPlace: GMSPlace?` (declared at class scope): the map moves there, adds a marker at that location, changes the `navigationItem.title` to the `selectedPlace.name`, and prints the website to the console - all good so far.

Now I'd like an info window to pop up when the marker is tapped, like I've done with some other default markers that I've hardcoded. Here's the infoWindow function:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

    let customInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomInfoWindow
    let placeName = marker.title!


    switch placeName {
    case "TGI Friday's":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "TGI Friday's"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Thoroughly Average Chain Restaurant"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "fridays")
        self.navigationItem.title = "TGI Friday's"
    case "George's":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "George's"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Old School Diner"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "georges")
        self.navigationItem.title = "George's"
    case "Reserve Cut":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "Reserve Cut"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Kosher Steakhouse"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "reserveCut")
        self.navigationItem.title = "Reserve Cut"
    case "O'Hara's":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "O'Hara's"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Irish Pub"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "oharas")
        self.navigationItem.title = "O'Hara's"
    case "Bill's Bar & Burger":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "Bill's Bar & Burger"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Bar founded by Bill that also has burgers"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "bills")
        self.navigationItem.title = "Bill's Bar & Burger"
    default:
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = self.selectedPlace?.name
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = self.selectedPlace?.formattedAddress
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "noImageFound")
        self.navigationItem.title = self.selectedPlace?.name
    }

    return customInfoWindow
}
```

My custom window pops up fine when I tap on my hardcoded default markers, but not with the user-selected place. The title pops up in the default info window but not my custom window. Does anybody know what's going on and how I can get this to work?

EDIT: If I `print(selectedPlace?.website)` in a different function, it's nil. Not sure why it works fine within the `pickPlace` function but not outside - that's why I set `self.selectedPlace = place`, so I could use it around my class.

Anyway that's what's causing the issue at hand I think, but I don't know why or how to fix it. So if anyone can help me fix it you're awesome.